# Image comparision in python

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, image-comparison

My objective is to find the difference between two images. The images are black and white engineering diagrams. Input will be a pair of diagrams of same component. One will be old diagram and another will be new diagram of the same component. My task is to find the difference between these two diagrams and create a new image to mark all the changes in the new diagram from the old one. Please suggest me some ways to do it using python.

Comment: provide example images please. what type of image are you talking about? what's the source of your image? camera? scanner? drawing program?

Comment: The image may be a circuit diagram or any hardware architecture diagram. Please refer the following link for example : https://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://s.eeweb.com/articles/2015/10/16/Designing-a-Low-Power-Flyback-Power-Supply-1444973977.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.eeweb.com/design-articles/designing-a-low-power-flyback-power-supply/&h=692&w=1024&tbnid=m4-Q1ijQIVMD2M:&docid=UQqLeCMVPmHGBM&ei=-6DBVqv_CYj1ugSP2LGQBw&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu&ved=0ahUKEwjr6IHVwPnKAhWIuo4KHQ9sDHIQMwgnKAswCw

Comment: do duplicates in both images match or is there some misalignment?